# Why are Black Holes important?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, astrophysics

We all know that black holes are really important. In astrophysics and gravitation, they are such an important test of General Relativity, for example.

But, what are the (other) reasons that make this kind of objects so important in Physics?

Comment: Would you care to explain you question more clearly?

Comment: I mean: what topics related to black holes make this objects important to study in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the major issues in physics today is that we don't really have a good way to unify general relativity and quantum field theory. Any attempt to incorporate gravity into quantum field theory is thwarted by the fact that gravity is so weak that we don't really understand how it works on a microscopic scale.

Near black holes, gravity is strong enough that the way it works on a microscopic level becomes very important. As such, black holes are essentially laboratories of quantum gravity; by studying their properties, we gain insights into the unification of these two fields that would be basically impossible to measure anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean: what topics related to black holes make this objects important to study in general. –

I see two main points, the importance for

1. theorists. Schwarzschild has found a vacuum solution of Einstein's field equations which is characterized by the so called event horizon. This boundary between the inside and the outside of a black hole can be understood as a lightlike surface. Nothing within this boundary can escape to the outside, not even light.
2. astronomers. They found evidence that there exist black holes and especially super massiv black holes in the center of galaxies. They further have detected the merger of black holes by means of a laser interferometer quite recently.